# Recovering old mac pro (A1278) MAC OS X LION installation failed

Tags: boot, mac, installation, osx-lion, installer

I had an old a mac a1278 and I wanted to format the disk and make a clean install. I used the apple boot tool to do so, but after erasing the disk and trying to reinstall Lion what happens is that the installation begins but the timer is extremely glitchy passing from -22k hours to zero and after a few minutes it fails telling me

> Failed to download additional components required

Now I can't boot into the Mac of course as I formatted the whole disk along with all the partitions it had and apparently I need another Mac to create a bootable usb installer. 
Any of you know how to fix this? I googled and the only fix were to lower the amount of ram to 4gb or connect the laptop via Ethernet. I tried the last but no results, as for the first the laptop shouldn't have more than 4GB of ram.

Excuse my terrible English in advance as I'm not a native speaker, thanks in advance for your help

Comment: a1278 doesn't narrow the field down sufficiently to advise; it covers 12 models. See EveryMac's [Ultimate Mac Lookup](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/) to try narrow down the specific model. Also, what was the last OS on the machine before it was wiped?…& also, precisely what happened when you tried wired Ethernet?

Comment: @Tetsujin excuse my late answer, I fixed it by trying over and over with ethernet. Might have been some comunication issues with Apple's servers